# Where else can I see which privileges I have earned?

Tags: support, privileges

Now, I go to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) when I want to see which privileges I have earned. It is inconvenient for me. Is there any other place in which I can see which privileges I have earned? Like this, I can see how many badges I have earned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/285645/xshsinap?tab=badges).

Comment: It took me a while to find the easiest path, but it's "help - help center -> scroll down -> privileges". I thought there used to be a link on your User page but the new user pages removed the link.

Comment: Were there a link on user's page? Are you sure?

Comment: I mean, in a roundabout way, there still is. Assuming you don't have all of the privileges, you can go to the activity tab on your profile, click on the progress bar for "next privilege" click on the "learn more" button... this takes you to the info for that specific privilege and then you can click the "privileges" button from there... but it's more clicking.

Comment: @Catija there's a link on your profile that works even if you have all the privileges, see my answer for details.

Comment: @RobertLongson In reality, all of the options take you to the same page, regardless. When I said the above, I meant that specific **path** is only available when one doesn't have all of the privileges. The OP isn't clear about how they are getting to the page right now.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges-on-users)... but there is no other place built into the site, sorry.

If you want to elaborate on *why* the existing way is inconvenient for you and propose a better solution, feel free to post a new [feature-request].

Answer (score 3):

1. Log in
2. Go to your profile (click on the picture on the top of the page)
3. Click on the Edit Profile & Settings tab
4. Click on the privileges link on the left a little way down the page

[image: Privilege page link]

Comment: Why does SE place the user's privilege in the tab? It is a little difficult to find. Why not create a new page in "Activity" tab? For example, I can see how many badges I have earned in the path which is "help -> help center - > badges". And I can see it in "Activity" tab too. I think it is convenient for me.

Comment: If you think there should be a link somewhere else in the profile, ask a question suggesting it and tag it as [feature-request] it as Anna Lear suggested in her answer.